# save blob audio file on server with xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, blob

I'm working on an audio web application where you can play along with music and record yourself. I'm working with a recorder plugin and I'm trying to save what has been recorded in a folder on a server. I get a blob file from the plugin via this javascript code:

```
recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = '../../audio/recordings/test.wav';
        xhr.open('POST',url,true);
        xhr.onload = function(e) {
            if (this.status == 200) {
              console.log(this.responseText);
            }
          };
        xhr.send(blob); 
        },'audio/wav');
```

I have never worked with this before so I'm not sure if my code is right. But I get no errors my file is just not saved. I have been searching the internet for this and what I have found is that a lot of people use a php file as url. Why? What php file are they using?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616010/saving-wav-file-recorded-in-chrome-to-server/16616519#16616519.