# Null parameter when trying to pass a blob to C# controller

Tags: c#, javascript, php, asp.net-mvc

So I am referring to [Saving WAV File Recorded in Chrome to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616010/saving-wav-file-recorded-in-chrome-to-server/16616519#16616519) to save a blob to my server. However, I cannot translate this PHP sentence in to C#.

```
<?php
// get the temporary name that PHP gave to the uploaded file
$tmp_filename=$_FILES["that_random_filename.wav"]["tmp_name"];
// rename the temporary file (because PHP deletes the file as soon as it's done with it)
rename($tmp_filename,"/tmp/uploaded_audio.wav");
?>
```

Here is what I've tried so far

**View**

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("that_random_filename.wav", blob);
xhr.open("POST", "SubmitSound", true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

**View model**

```
public class SoundBlob
{        
    public string key { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase blob { get; set; } // I tried byte[] and string too
}
```

**Controller**

```
       [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubmitSound(SoundBlob blob)
        {
            // Create the new, empty data file.
            string fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "/Content/Sound/" + Environment.TickCount + ".wav";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
            BinaryWriter w = new BinaryWriter(fs);

            blob.blob.SaveAs(blob.key);
            w.Close();
            fs.Close();           
            return new JsonResult() { Data = "Saved successfully" };
        }
```

Both `key` and `blob` of `SoundBlob` is null! How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not rely on a type of C#, rather using this script.

```
            var length = Request.ContentLength;
            var bytes = new byte[length];
            Request.InputStream.Read(bytes, 0, length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Client:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" ></script>
<div class='wrapper' >
    <input type='file' class='target' id='targetinput' />
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("blob.blob", document.getElementById('targetinput').files[0]);
xhr.open("POST", "/Home/SubmitSound", true);
xhr.send(fd);
```

**Server:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitSound(SoundBlob blob)
{
        var fileName = Server.MapPath(string.Format("/Content/Sound/{0}.wav", Environment.TickCount));
        blob.blob.SaveAs(fileName);
        return new JsonResult { Data = "Saved successfully" };
}
```

Perfectly works, i just checked it out

Comment: My apologize, I do not provide enough background information. Basically, I am using a javascript library to record a file, when the recording is done, a `blob` is passed to a function to save it to the client machine. If you view the source of http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html, you can see the function `doneEncoding`, which is what I am trying to modify.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is user can click on a button, record their voice, and click on the same button again, then the `blob` can be uploaded to the database. Your solution requires people to select a file, I am afraid.

Comment: This did it for me. Great job.