# Upload recorded speech to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

Recordjs library record user's speech, write it in a blob and force the user to download it as a WAV file ([demo](http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html), works only on Chrome).

I don't want to download the WAV but rather, upload the blob to database for further processing. My solution is built based on .NET MVC

I've tried a lot of different ways but none of them meets my need, mainly because I cannot find a data type to represent the blob sent to the controller. Could you please give me some idea?

[Another question related to the same problem but the solution was built on PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616010/saving-wav-file-recorded-in-chrome-to-server/16616519#16616519)