# handling BLOB and uploading .wav file recorded with recorder.js and HTML5

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob, html5-audio, blobstorage

Reference to this conversation's last answer:
[Question-Answer-Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616010/saving-wav-file-recorded-in-chrome-to-server)
I am unable to debug and fix files and run code correctly. I see that it is flagged as helpful and correct. Can someone help me understand file structure needed to fix this? I am unable to run this code.

- MAIN ISSUE: I am trying to save recorded audio to server.
- My BLOB url is: blob:http%3A//localhost/7bc08d6c-8862-45b5-b567-040fd14ef4aa
- I am using recorder.js

Thanks!

Comment: Which piece of the code exactly are you having trouble with? Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: function upload(blob) {
  var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload=function(e) {
      if(this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log("Server returned: ",e.target.responseText));
      }
  };
  var fd=new FormData();
  fd.append("that_random_filename.wav",blob);
  xhr.open("POST","<url>",true);
  xhr.send(fd);
}

Comment: i tried by changing <url> values but no use

Comment: You need a blob not a blob url.

Answer (score 0):

```
const constructUploadData = (file: any, data: { audioQueueId: string | Blob; fileName: string | Blob }) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('audioQueueId', data.audioQueueId);
    formData.append('fileName', data.fileName);
    if (file) {
        formData.append('file', new Blob(file ? [file] : [], { type: file.type }));
    }
    return formData;
};
     


const uploadAudioInBackground = (file: any, data: any) => {
    return axios.post(`clip/upload`, constructUploadData(file, data), {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
    });
};
```