# How to post blob and string with XMLHttpRequest javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, blob

I'm trying to post an audio blob and a string to my server with javascript XMLHttpRequest.  The server code is PHP.  I can manage to post the string, but the blob is not going through:

Javascript:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("string", words);
formData.append("blobData", clipBlob);

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://www.website.com/file.php";
xmlhttp.responseType = 'json';
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);

xmlhttp.onload = function () {
console.log(xmlhttp.response[0]);
console.log(xmlhttp.response[1]);

};     
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

PHP:

```
$sentence = $_POST["string"];
$blob = $_POST["blobData"];

file_put_contents("clip.wav",$blob);
$aud = 'clip.wav';
$audData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($aud));
$src = 'data:audio/wav;base64,'.$audData;

echo json_encode(array($sentence,$src));
```

The $sentence variable echos back to my html page, but the $src doesn't.  In fact, the wav file is empty because the blob info isn't being recognized.

EDIT:
I changed the PHP for the blob to this and it worked:

```
// get the temporary name that PHP gave to the uploaded file
$tmp_filename=$_FILES["blobData"]["tmp_name"];
// rename the temporary file (because PHP deletes the file as soon as it's done with it)
rename($tmp_filename,"clip.wav");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16616519/3080392

Comment: Check PHP post_max_size and upload_max_filesize INI settings. What is in clipBlob? How are you sure it's correct data? Do proper 'multipart/fomr-data' POST, refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax finally var_dump($_POST) on the server side to see exactly what you receive.

Comment: @marekful clipBlob looks like this Blob(168468) {size: 168468, type: "audio/wav"}. post_max_size and upload_max_filesize are 8M and 2M respectively, so they are plenty big for my audio clip size. var_dump produced null